# java.lang.indexOutOfBoundsException in ActionBar.tabsListener

Tags: android, exception, android-actionbar

I use a tabsListener for my ActionBar Tabs to set the tabs. In my phoneUi is everything "fine", but in my tabletUi it throws a exception.

```
09-15 15:46:27.588: W/System.err(31772): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.getTabAt(ActionBarImpl.java:1168)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper.getTabAt(ActionBarWrapper.java:423)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at de.arvidg.onlineradio.StartActivity.onPageSelected(StartActivity.java:1270)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:445)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:405)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:386)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at de.arvidg.onlineradio.TabsListener.onTabSelected(TabsListener.java:27)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper$TabWrapper.onTabSelected(ActionBarWrapper.java:344)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:570)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:499)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:485)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper.addTab(ActionBarWrapper.java:377)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at de.arvidg.onlineradio.StartActivity.tabletUI(StartActivity.java:403)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at de.arvidg.onlineradio.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:310)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2136)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2207)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
09-15 15:46:27.799: W/System.err(31772):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The method which throw the exception:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onTabSelected tag = " + mTag);
    try { mPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt(mTag)); }
    catch(Exception e) { Log.e("TAG", "mPager.setCurrentItem Exception " + e); e.printStackTrace(); Log.d("TabListener", "Error onTabSelected = " + e); }
}
```

any ideas? need more code, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your size of fragments is 1, but you are passing the index 1. This means that there are two `Fragments`, one at index 0, and another at index 1. Collections are count from 0, so you should do this:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onTabSelected tag = " + mTag);
    try { mPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt(mTag) - 1); }   ///CHANGED IT TO -1
    catch(Exception e) { Log.e("TAG", "mPager.setCurrentItem Exception " + e);
        e.printStackTrace(); Log.d("TabListener", "Error onTabSelected = " + e); }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I copied my two fragment from my phoneUi to my tabletUi and forgot to change the indexNumbers. So only a fragment number 1 and fragment number 2 exist and no fragment number 0.
I changed the numbers to 0 and 1 and it works. Thanks a lot!